# How to handle new user with significant amount of closed questions

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, new-users

I have noticed recently a number of new users who have a significant amount of closed questions.  One [user](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/8226) in particular has around 50% of 28 questions asked that have been closed.  A lot of the questions asked are inane and completely useless and it seems fairly obvious that this user has not read the FAQ.

How do we handle new users like this?  What's the best way to teach them what makes a good question?

Answer (score 1):

There is a community auto-flag that trips when a user has consecutive closed questions, alerting moderators to the problem.

If it's an issue that you feel hasn't been addressed or needs immediate attention, feel free to flag one of the user's questions with your concerns and it'll be looked into.

Answer (score -2):

Be polite and ask him why he cares so much in the comments.  I have no idea why anyone would waste their time doing what he's doing if he wasn't the least bit interested in the answer.

I can't see what kind of personal gain he's getting out of doing what he's doing (doesn't appear to be selling anything more than M$ vehemence) other than maybe getting to see what the advanced tools look like by getting +5 rep here and there, which he'll loose as soon as he's gained when we go out of beta.